# flutter pub run build_runner build not working

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-null-safety, flutter-hive

when running flutter pub run build_runner build I get this error.

```
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:258:50: Error: The property 'displayString' is defined in multiple extensions for 'TargetKind' and neither is more specific.
 - 'TargetKind' is from 'package:meta/meta_meta.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.7.0/lib/meta_meta.dart').
Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
        var kindNames = kinds.map((kind) => kind.displayString).toList()
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:1950:14: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  String get displayString {
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.7.0/lib/meta_meta.dart:91:14: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  String get displayString {
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:260:36: Error: The getter 'commaSeparatedWithOr' isn't defined for the class 'List<dynamic>'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'commaSeparatedWithOr'.
        var validKinds = kindNames.commaSeparatedWithOr;
```

Comment: update the version of build_runner it will be work fine

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This issue is related to outdated dependencies most likely, I had a similar one just today.

Run `flutter pub upgrade` and it should work!

Answer (score 9):

```
dependency_overrides:
  watcher: ^1.1.0
```

Add these two lines in `pubspec.yaml` if you are facing:

> "The class 'FileSystemEvent' can't be extended, implemented, or mixed in outside of its library because it's a sealed class.
> abstract class _ConstructableFileSystemEvent implements FileSystemEvent {
> "

Comment: This solution worked for me. Care to explain what's going on here?

Comment: In my case I added these lines but I also needed to add pub_semver: ^2.1.4 as an additional dependency override before the error was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

> dart pub upgrade will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Those who are experiencing this problem, just overwrite the `"meta"` dependency.

just add these lines to pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
meta: 1.6.0
```

This might solve your issue, and there is well discussed github discussion https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46687